# How to ignore duplicates records of a large table when using Copy Binary in postgres

Tags: postgresql, copy, bulkinsert, npgsql

I am trying to do bulk insert data in postgres using Binary copy, as below

```
await connection.BeginBinaryImportAsync($"COPY ph_numbers FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY));
```

This table already contains millions of records and I just want to ignore the records already present there.

I went through the documentation and could not find any efficient way to ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to ignore duplicates.

You can `COPY` the data to a temporary table and then use `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` to merge the data into your existing table.